# Ajax form submit not working, returns 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to work out a submit contact form through ajax but somehow i fail in process and i can't figure out, every combination i try it returns `0` for some reason.

This is my form

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group wow fadeInUp">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" name="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group wow fadeInUp">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" name="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group wow fadeInUp">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" name="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 wow fadeInUp">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                </form>
```

And this is the ajax script in included.

```
 $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        console.log(name + email + message);
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        var data = $form.serialize();
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_contact.ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            action: 'ajax_contact',
            data: ajax_contact.data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.status == "success") {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').append("<strong>" + data.message + "</strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                }
                if(data.status == "error") {
                    // Error message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>" + data.message + "</strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});
```

And i properly added to functions.php

```
function ajax_contact() {
try {
if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
  throw new Exception('Bad form parameters. Check the markup to make sure you are naming the inputs correctly.');
}
if (!is_email($_POST['email'])) {
  throw new Exception('Email address not formatted correctly.');
}
$website_email = !empty(get_theme_option('contact_email')) ? get_theme_option('contact_email') : get_bloginfo('admin_email');
$subject = 'Website Contact Form from: '.$_POST['name'];
$headers = 'From: '.get_bloginfo('name').' Contact Form ' .$website_email;
$send_to = $website_email;
$subject = get_bloginfo('name') . " Contact Form: " .$_POST['name'];
$message = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n\nMessage:\n". $_POST['message'] . "";

if (wp_mail($send_to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Contact message sent.'));
  exit;
} else {
  throw new Exception('Failed to send email. Check AJAX handler.');
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()));
exit;
}
die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_contact', 'ajax_contact' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_contact', 'ajax_contact' );

function ajax_contact_js() {
wp_localize_script('ajax-contact', 'ajax_contact', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_contact_js');
```

And i also enqueued all the scripts that needed in separate function, so i don't get any errors and seems that everything is included and properly added but in function it fails somehow and i always get response 0.

Comment: A simple suggestion, but try `print_r($_POST);` at the beginning of the `ajax_contact` function to see if anything is coming back. If you see your posted data, then there's an issue with your if/else/try statements. Since you're seeing 0 come back I'm guessing the earlier if statements are throwing the exception but not returning any data to the ajax script.

Comment: @Tom it looks like function is not receiving anything from $_POST when i try to print_r i get empty array like none of inputs are caught, but that's confusing because if i do console.log(name) the ajax looks like it caught that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i made it working like this.

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                            <div class="form-group wow fadeInUp">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" name="name" required data-error="Please enter your name.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors text-danger"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group wow fadeInUp">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" name="email" required data-error="Please enter your email address.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors text-danger"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group wow fadeInUp">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" name="message" required data-error="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors text-danger"></div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 wow fadeInUp">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ajax_contact" />
                            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'contact_nonce', 'contact_nonce' ); ?>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                </form>
```

As you can see on the form i added `method` to `post` and `action` to `wordpress ajax url`
I also added hidden field with value to registered action hook and nonce field.

And in javascript file i changed to this

```
$('#contactForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post( $form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), 'json')
      .done(function( data ) {
          var response = JSON.parse(data);
          if(response.status == "success") {
            // Success message
            $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
            $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
            $('#success > .alert-success').append("<strong>" + response.message + "</strong>");
            $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
            //clear all fields
            $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        } else if(response.status == "error") {
            // Error message
            $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>" + response.message + "</strong>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
            //clear all fields
            $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        } else {
            // Fail message
              $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
              $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
              $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
              $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
              //clear all fields
              $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        }
      })
      .fail(function() {
          // Fail message
            $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
            //clear all fields
            $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
      });
```

The most important part was `JSON.parse`
And function and registered hooks in .php file remain unchanged, only thing i added was check for nonce field.

Answer (score 2):

The `action: 'ajax_contact'` part in:

```
var data = $form.serialize();
console.log(data);
$.ajax({
    url: ajax_contact.ajaxurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    action: 'ajax_contact',
    data: ajax_contact.data,
```

is most likely the cause here, that your ajax request is failing.

Move the *action* part into the *data* set instead.

Since you're serializing the form data, you could try to add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="ajax_contact" />
```

into your form.

Also make sure the data attribute:

```
data: ajax_contact.data,
```

is getting the serialized data, but not the undefined `ajax_contact.data`.

You can try with manual json string instead for testing.

ps: also consider using [*nonce*](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) for extra security.